# If {fn} converges pointwise to {f} and each {fn} is bounded in a closed interval [a,b], is {f} also bounded in [a,b]?

Tags: real-analysis, pointwise-convergence

Is it possible to say that if $f_n$ converges **pointwise** to $f$ and each $f_n$ is bounded in the **closed interval** $[a,b]$, then $f$ is also bounded in $[a,b]$?

As far as I know, boundness is not preserved in pointwise convergence. This is easy to see with an example such as:
$$f_n=\frac{n}{nx+1},x\in(0,1)$$
where $f_n$ is bounded in $(0,1)$ but $f$ isn't.

However, I'm not sure if this conclusion holds with a closed interval.

I was thinking
$$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{x-(1+\frac{1}{n})},x\in[0,1]$$
where $f_n$ is bounded in $[0,1]$ but $f$ isn't. Does this example work?

Comment: Choose countably many pairwise distinct points $x_k$ in the interval. Consider the function $f$ which has value $f(x_k) =k$ at the chosen points and $0$ elsewhere. Can you write $f$ as a pointwise limit of bounded functions?

Comment: If you're not assuming that the $f_n$ are continuous, then it doesn't matter at all whether the endpoints of the interval are included (indeed, the structure of the domain doesn't matter at all other than its cardinality).

Answer (score 1):

The example does not work because $f_n(1) = -n$, thus $(f_n)$ does not converge pointwise. But you can easily modify your example:

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x-(1+\frac{1}{n})} & x \le 1 -\frac 1 n \\ -\frac n 2 + \frac{n^2}{2}(x - (1 -\frac 1 n)) & x  \ge  1 -\frac 1 n \end{cases} $$
Since both parts of the definition give $f_n(1 - \frac 1 n) = -\frac n 2$, these functions are continuous, thus bounded. If $x < 1$, then for $n \ge \frac{1}{1-x}$ we get $x \le 1 -\frac 1 n$ and therefore
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{x-(1+\frac{1}{n})} = \frac{1}{x-1} .$$
Moreover, all $f_n(1) = 0$, thus
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(1) = 0 .$$
Thus $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x-1} & x < 1 \\ 0 & x  = 1 \end{cases} $$
This function is unbounded and non-continuous at $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be any unbounded function on $[a,b]$ and define $f_n(x)=f(x) $ if $-n\leq f(x) \leq n$, $f_n(x)=n$ if $f(x) >n$ and $f_n(x)=-n$ if $f(x) <-n$. Then, for each $x$,  $f_n(x)=f(x)$ for $n$ sufficiently large so $f_n \to f$ pointwise. Also $|f_n(x)| \leq n$ for all $x,n$.